# Information about the method which throws Access Denied exception when using @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

We have used Spring security to secure our rest endpoints. Every rest resource is annotated with a @PreAuthorize annotation. When the caller doesn't have access to the resource that he requests for Spring security throws a org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException exception.
We have an exception mapper which returns this message with appropriate error code 403 to the clients.

```
public class AccessDeniedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<AccessDeniedException> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessDeniedExceptionMapper.class);
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper#toResponse(java.lang.Throwable)
     */
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(AccessDeniedException exception) {
        LOGGER.debug("Access is denied: {}",exception.getMessage());
        ResponseBuilder bldr = Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN);
        bldr.entity("Access is denied").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
        return bldr.build();

    }

}
```

Now, is it possible to get the information about the method [someMethod in this case] which actually throws this exception? 
The idea is to throw custom exceptions to the clients based on the resource they access.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ACTN_START_STOP_DB') and hasPermission(#databaseId, {'ACTN_START_STOP_DB'})")
@Path("/db")
public DatabaseOperation someMethod(){
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea provide information in this case to the client, they can not solve it, and in some cases can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the HttpHeaders object to the mapper with the following annotation:

```
@Context
HttpHeaders headers;
```

From there you might be able to pull your needed context data.